# table-lookup directive in my wrangler using datafusion

Tags: google-cloud-platform, directive, google-cloud-data-fusion, cdap

I'm trying to use the table-lookup :country_code 'country_lookup_table'  directive in a wrangler in  my datafusion pipeline but I'm getting Error encountered while executing 'table-lookup' : Dataset 'country_lookup_table' could not be instantiated. Make sure that a dataset 'country_lookup_table' of type Table exists.
country_code column is in the input in my wrangler and I have a lookup table in bigquery 'country_lookup_table'.
May I ask if I have omitted any steps

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

'table-lookup' directive is not supported for lookup from BigQuery. This is the JIRA with the feature request - https://cdap.atlassian.net/browse/CDAP-16145, but is not part of a plan for any release at the moment . Please see https://cdap.atlassian.net/wiki/spaces/DOCS/pages/382108315/Joiner+Analytics as a possible alternative.